# Using controller::class in Route::resource is causing namespace to be included two times resulting in Controller Not Found

Tags: php, laravel, controller

I have a Laravel application where I'm getting exception controller does not exist due to wrong namespace. The namespace is getting repeated two times causing this issue. I don't know why it's repeating and I've been searching on internet but nothing found related to this.

```
Target class [App\Http\Controllers\App\Http\Controllers\customerController] does not exist.
```

The namespace here is being repeated which is causing the error. The namespace set in RouteServiceProvider is below:

```
protected $namespace = 'App\\Http\\Controllers';
```

My routes in routes/web.php file are:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\customerController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

Route::resource("customers", customerController::class);
```

### Solution

If I use old Laravel syntax then the error goes away:

```
Route:resource("customers", "customerController");
```

But I want to know why the above approach is behaving strangely. I'm using Laravel 8 in this project.

### Update

I was doing one thing wrong. We don't have to specify **namespace** in `RouteServiceProvider` if we want to use classes as routes. I added namespace in routes services provider, that's why when I was using class syntax, it included namespace twice causing error. But when I used string based controller name then namespace resolved correctly.

Answer (score 1):

```
use App\Http\Controllers\CustomerController;
```

use capital letter for starting of controller name

then

```
Route::resource('customers', CustomerController::class);
```

Comment: I know, for some reason we have used camel case I don't think this is causing the issue. Because I have already worked on other projects with camelCase naming convention.

Comment: you error show [App\Http\Controllers\App\Http\Controllers\customerController] its taking two time remove the protected $namespace = 'App\\Http\\Controllers'; from RouteServiceProvider  and try again

Comment: Issue fixed, how's that possible? we need to import class then reference it? How is it being used without reference and error?

Comment: if you are using namespace in route you dint have to need to add RouteServiceProvider